# Is there a lower and upper bound for the following expression which looks similar to Rayleigh quotient?

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

The expression looks very similar to that of Rayleigh quotient, but it not the same. Can I find the lower and upper bounds in terms of eigenvalues? If so, how do I proceed?

$ \log \frac{det(B^H S B)}{det(B^H B)} $

Also, note $S$ can be expressed as follows: $ S = y y^H $

Rayleigh quotient: $ \frac{b^H S b}{b^H b} $